# How can I fix this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I want to answer this question: In each year from 1962-2015, which New York Met hit the most home runs. In my results, I want to see the player's name, number of homers hit, and year. But in my results, I am getting the wrong player's name.

**Here are the results I am getting:**

1962    andercr01   34
1963    andercr01   17
1964    altmage01   20
1965    bearnla01   19
    And so on.

**Here is my query:**

```
SELECT yearID, playerID, MAX(HR) as maxHR
FROM Batting
WHERE teamID='NYN'
GROUP BY yearID;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `join`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Batting b JOIN
     (SELECT yearID, teamID, MAX(HR) as maxHR
      FROM Batting
      WHERE teamID = 'NYN'
      GROUP BY yearID, teamId
     ) bb
     ON bb.yearId = b.yearId and bb.teamId = b.teamId and bb.maxHR = b.HR;
```

Note:  this will give duplicates in years where two players have the same maximum number of `HR`.

Also, I would expect the abbreviation for the New York Mets to be "NYM", not "NYN".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the join is overkill for this query as well.

Comment: Gordon, your query works. The only thing is that it is displaying all the columns in the Batting table, and I just want these displayed in each row: yearID, playerID, and # homers. BTW, in the table, 'NYN' is the Mets abbreviation.

Comment: Gordon, I was able to answer what I wrote about in my previous comment to you with this: SELECT b.yearID, b.playerID, b.HR. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT yearID, playerName, MAX(HR) as maxHR
FROM Batting
WHERE teamID='NYN'
GROUP BY yearID;
```

You're not selecting the players name in your original query.

Comment: To commenters: I made a mistake in my post and apologize. A player name is appearing, but it is the wrong name. I have revised the original post. BTW, I never expected such quick responses.

Comment: It's because you're selecting the players ID and not their name, if there's no player name column in that table you'll have to do a join on the players table and compare the ids to get the proper name.

Comment: I can understand that someone would provide this answer.  I don't understand the upvote, because the answer is wrong.  It will return an arbitrary player, not the one with the largest value of `HR`.

Comment: Celt: After thinking more about what you wrote, I tried to also display a player's full name, but have been unsuccessful. To Gordon's query (below), how would I "join" a third table called Master, which contains the fields nameFirst and nameLast that I can add to my first select via this: CONCAT(nameFirst, " ", nameLast). The Master table and the Batting table both have the playerID field.